# Math with direct input

Tags: python, math, input

I just started my first day at uni and there is one of the exercises I am already struggling with. This is the problem: Make code that inputs two given mumbers and output one minus the other

I did this:

```
number1 = int(raw_input("Type your first number: "))
number2 = int(raw_input("Type your second number: "))
result = number1 - number2
print result
```

But it was wrong because the input is direct so when the program tested my code it said:
[image]

I have always done code that first asks for the information so I have no idea if this is even possible in python or how you do it. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This works in my ubuntu

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting down votes. I have practised a lot of python in the summer to prepare for my degree, just never seen the map function before. Sorry if this offended someone.

Comment: It's not the map function that was the problem.  It's that you used `raw_input` to generate output when none was expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use :

```
number1, number2 = map(int, raw_input().split())
result = number1 - number2
print result
```

In the sample input both the numbers are separated by space, and there is no prompt for the user such as `"Type your first number: "`, So all yo need to do is take input using `raw_input()`, then splitting the input on `" "`(space) by using `.split()` and then converting each string after splitting to `int` using the `map` function.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the explanation, very helpful answer. I will research more on the map function which I haven´t seen before. Thanks.

Comment: @jonathan9879: As well as needing to be able to take in both numbers in a single `raw_input()` call, this is also about your course's automatic grading function wanting a specific output and only that output. By including a message in your `raw_input()` call, you create extra output that the grader doesn't want to see.

Comment: I think list comprehension would be easier to understand for a beginner: `number1, number2 = [int(number) for number in raw_input().split()]`